# How to fetch data from gun js in React

Tags: reactjs, gun

I got stuck at fetching data from gun js

```js
gun.get("messages").map().on((data, id) => console.log(data.title));
```

This `data` contains an objects with two properties `title` and `id`.

But I am getting an error:

```sh
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, could you please share your react component code as well. Also, creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help us long way in giving you more accurate answers.

Comment: I finally got the answer just use .open() method instead of .map() method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.